# Kubernetes: Is it possible to mount volumes to a container running as a CronJob?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I'm attempting to create a Kubernetes CronJob to run an application every minute.

A prerequisite is that I need to get my application code onto the container that runs within the CronJob. I figure that the best way to do so is to use a persistent volume, a pvclaim, and then defining the volume and mounting it to the container. I've done this successfully with containers running within a Pod, but it appears to be impossible within a CronJob? Here's my attempted configuration:

```
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: update_db
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: application-code
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: application-code-pv-claim
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: update-fingerprints
            image: python:3.6.2-slim
            command: ["/bin/bash"]
            args: ["-c", "python /client/test.py"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

The corresponding error:

> error: error validating "cron-applications.yaml": error validating
>   data: found invalid field volumes for v2alpha1.CronJobSpec; if you
>   choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with
>   --validate=false

I can't find any resources that show that this is possible. So, if not possible, how does one solve the problem of getting application code into a running CronJob?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#cronjob-v1beta1-batch) uses a PodTemplate as everything else based on Pods and can use Volumes. You placed your Volume specification directly in the CronJobSpec instead of the [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#podspec-v1-core), use it like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: update-db
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: update-fingerprints
            image: python:3.6.2-slim
            command: ["/bin/bash"]
            args: ["-c", "python /client/test.py"]
            volumeMounts:
            - name: application-code
              mountPath: /where/ever
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: application-code
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: application-code-pv-claim
```

Answer (score 3):

For the other question in there: "how does one solve the problem of getting application code into a running CronJob?"

You build your own image that contains the code. This is how it is normally done.

```
FROM python:3.6.2-slim
ADD test.py /client/test.py

CMD ['python','-c','/client/test.py']
```

Build and push to the docker registry.

```sh
docker build -t myorg/updatefingerprints
docker push myorg/updatefingerprints
```

Use this image in the descriptor.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: update_db
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: application-code
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: application-code-pv-claim
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: update-fingerprints
            image: myorg/update-fingerprints
            imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

This requires thinking quite differently about configuration management and version control.

Answer (score 2):

now there is ephemeral. available since 1.21

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/#generic-ephemeral-volumes

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: my-frontend
      image: busybox:1.28
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/scratch"
        name: scratch-volume
      command: [ "sleep", "1000000" ]
  volumes:
    - name: scratch-volume
      ephemeral:
        volumeClaimTemplate:
          spec:
            accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: I'm seeing `storageclass.storage.k8s.io "scratch-storage-class" not found` I must be doing something wrong. Do I need to create storage class first?

Comment: storageclass is optional parameter. if not specified, default will be used
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/

Comment: I'm confused how do I create this ephemeral storage class? How do I use it? It's not available in my definitions and not standard in azure.

Comment: CronJob  .spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.volumes[ephemeral]

Comment: Ok that makes sense now, I was using a storage class that didn't exist and ephemeral can use any storage class that is available or default if omitted. My issue now is the Job shows a warning for the PVC after it completes. Lens showing Warning PVC not found after successful completion of the job.

Comment: Yes, that is the meaning of ephemeral. A disk is created for the duration of the work and deleted after use. With this approach, kube nodes have a small root disk.

Comment: After the conrjob finishes the warning says the PVC says its deleted, only when another cornjob is ran the previous one is deleted. I can still see the pv and the pvc listed even after the job is finished.