# Kubernetes CronJob to run Python script

Tags: python, kubernetes

I am trying to schedule Python Script through Kubernetes CronJob but for some reason I am not able to understand how can I do it. I am able to run simple script like `echo Hello World` but that's not what I want

I tried using this specification:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: "Forbid"
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 10
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 600 # 10 min
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 0
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 3300 # 55min
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: hello
              image: python:3.6-slim
              command: ["python"]
              args: ["./main.py"]
          restartPolicy: Never
```

But then I am not able to run it because main.py is not found, I understand that relative path is not supported so I hardcoded the path but then I am not able to find my home directory, I tried doing `ls /home/` and over there my folder name is not visible so I am not able to access my project repository.

Initially I was planning to run bash script which can do:

1. Install requirements by `pip install requirements.txt`
2. Then run Python script

But I am not sure how can I do this with kubernetes, It is so confusing to me

In short I want to be able to run k8s CronJob which can run Python script by first installing requirements and then running it

Comment: You are not able to run it because you're using the image `python:3.6-slim`. In order to make it work you need to create your own image based on `python:3.6-slim`. Please look the [following link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to understand how to build your own image. Then you need to be able to see your image with kubernetes.

Comment: @Shashank Sharma did you solve this issue or it's still valid question?

Answer (score 1):

where is the startup script ./main.py located? is it present in the image.
you need to build new image using python:3.6-slim as base image and add your python script to PATH. then you would be able to run it from k8s CronJob

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this answer could help you: [Kubernetes: Is it possible to mount volumes to a container running as a CronJob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578331/kubernetes-is-it-possible-to-mount-volumes-to-a-container-running-as-a-cronjob)

You can mount a script as a Volume if you don't want to build your own docker image.

Here is an example

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-scripts
data:
  script.py: |
    print('Hello, world!')
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: python:3.11-alpine
            args: ["python", "/tmp/python/script.py"]
            volumeMounts:
            - name: scripts
              mountPath: /tmp/python
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
          - name: scripts
            configMap:
              name: test-scripts
```